# Venti Events causing failed DeleteStaleTemplateCaches task

Tags: plugins

As you can see from the craft.log, venti is causing an issue with template refresh:

```
2016/01/19 10:59:27 [info] [application] [Forced] Starting step 242 of 828 total steps.

2016/01/19 10:59:27 [info] [application] [Forced] Starting step 243 of 828 total steps.

2016/01/19 10:59:27 [error] [system.db.CDbCommand] CDbCommand::fetchAll() failed: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'venti.startDate' in 'order clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `elements`.`id`, `entries`.`sectionId`, `entries`.`typeId`, `entries`.`authorId`, `entries`.`postDate`, `entries`.`expiryDate`

FROM `craft_elements` `elements`

JOIN `craft_elements_i18n` `elements_i18n` ON elements_i18n.elementId = elements.id

JOIN `craft_content` `content` ON content.elementId = elements.id

JOIN `craft_entries` `entries` ON entries.id = elements.id

JOIN `craft_sections` `sections` ON sections.id = entries.sectionId

LEFT JOIN `craft_structures` `structures` ON structures.id = sections.structureId

WHERE (((elements_i18n.locale = :locale) AND (content.locale = :locale)) AND (elements.archived = 0)) AND (elements_i18n.enabled = 1)

GROUP BY `elements`.`id`

ORDER BY `venti`.`startDate` ASC LIMIT 5.

2016/01/19 10:59:27 [error] [application] Encountered an error running task 5 (DeleteStaleTemplateCaches), step 243 of 828: An exception was thrown: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'venti.startDate' in 'order clause'
```

Has anybody else had this issue? Frustrating as it means my cache isn't working properly, causing 'Failed Task' to show up in the Admin for the client and I'm not sure but may be affecting other areas of the site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing that will end up being a bug... have you tried contacting the [developer](https://venti.helpdocs.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.9.14 is still the beta version.  Go into the Venti_EventManageService file and delete the two lines with this string `craft()->templateCache->deleteCachesByElement($element);`.

Comment: I've followed your instructions, commenting out those 2 instances of `craft()->templateCache->deleteCachesByElement($element);`, and I have cancelled all failed tasks, followed by clearing the caches. Let's see how it pans out tomorrow. Thanks for your swift response.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. No failed tasks since doing what you said. Thanks so much!